# Adding vertical space in a multi-line equation while using IEEEeqnarray

Tags: spacing, equations, ieeetran

how can I add vertical space between lines in an equation while using IEEEeqnarray?

Comment: Please add a small example of your use of the ieeeeqnarray environment. Also, are you looking to change the space between successive lines globally or on a one-off basis?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the optional argument for `\\`:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{c}
a = b\\[5pt]
c=d
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can change the setting once for the entire equation?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change the spacing for all the lines in the current `IEEEeqnarray` environment you can use:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}{\setlength{\IEEEnormaljot}{15pt}%
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{c}
a = b\\
c=d\\
e=f
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
}
\end{document}
```

Note the additional `{` which makes the setting local to this group and does not affect other `IEEEeqnarray` environments.  Alternatively you could define your own environment that contains this setting:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\newenvironment{MyIEEEeqnarray}[1][c]{%
    \setlength{\IEEEnormaljot}{15pt}%
    \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{#1}%
}{%
    \end{IEEEeqnarray}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{MyIEEEeqnarray}[c]
a = b\\
c=d\\
e=f
\end{MyIEEEeqnarray}
\end{document}
```

Here I made the `[c]` setting optional.

Comment: I only want extra space for the lines of the equation itself. In other words, only part enclosed in `\begin{IEEEeqnarray}... \end{IEEEeqnarray}`.

Comment: The above will ONLY affect spacing in the current `IEEEeqnarray` as it is in a group.

Comment: Actually, there is no need to wrap around the `IEEEeqnarray` environment. The `\IEEEeqnarraydecl` hook or the optional argument of the `IEEEeqnarray` environment can be used instead.

Comment: @mhp: Thanks, I did not know about that. But I personally prefer to wrap it in an environment, as then it is going to be consistent across the entire document.

Comment: Settings specified in the `\IEEEeqnarraydecl` hook apply to every instance of the `IEEEeqnarray` environment in the document. You can override them for a single instance using the optional argument. Note furthermore that setting `\IEEEnormaljot` only works because `\jot` is initialized as `\IEEEnormaljot` in the standard set-up of the `IEEEeqnarray` environment.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `\jot` length in the `\IEEEeqnarraydecl` hook:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\renewcommand*{\IEEEeqnarraydecl}{%
  \setlength{\jot}{2\IEEEnormaljot}% twice the normal value of \jot
}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{RCL}
  a&=&b\\
  x&=&y
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can set `\jot` in the optional argument of the `IEEEeqnarray` environment. Note that, in both cases, the change of `\jot` is only local.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `gather`, but if working within the `array` environment, just add vertical space to line jumps. It may work with `gather`.

If  used often, define a new line jump command.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\lj}{\vspace*{2mm}\\} % vertical space is added

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{c}
  Line 1 \lj
  Line 2 \lj
  Line 3 \lj
  Line 4 \lj
  Line 5
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: a) This doesn't seem to address the particular question of the IEEE environments and b) in such an approach you would be better with `\\[2mm]` as in Gonzalo Medina's answer.